# Change camera position when following player in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I have created a walking character in Unity 3D and I watched a tutorial to make a script that makes the player follow the camera which is good but I want the camera to be lower done and to be rotated more backwards so that the camera can see more of the world as right now not much is visible passed the player. I have attached a link to an image of what it looks like now.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBWcV.jpg
as you can see you can't see much of what's in front of the player.

Next I will attach the script and hopefully you can show me what code needs adding or changing to allow my changes to be possible.

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform playerObject;

public float distanceFromObject = 6f;
void Update()
{
    Vector3 lookOnObject = playerObject.position - transform.position;
    lookOnObject = playerObject.position - transform.position;
    transform.forward = lookOnObject.normalized;

    Vector3 playerLastPosition;
    playerLastPosition = playerObject.position - lookOnObject.normalized * distanceFromObject;

    playerLastPosition.y = playerObject.position.y + distanceFromObject / 2;
    transform.position = playerLastPosition;
}
```

Thank you in advance for helping me. This is for a school project so I really hope that your solutions are great and can't wait to hear from you!

Answer (score -1):

You're looking into adding an offset to the camera relative to the look position of the camera. What you need to do is to offset the `playerObject.position` when you assign it to the `lookOnObject`.

Add a new vector3 and call it as an `lookOffset`. It will now become `lookOnObject = (playerObject.position + lookOffset) - transform.position`. It will act as a pitch control for your camera.

Use `distanceFromObject` to control the z position of the camera.

[EDIT]

Here's the altered script that I made. As mentioned above, you need to offset the position that the camera will look to. In this script, instead of a Vector3, I used float:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;`

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform playerObject;

    //Controls the pitch of the camera where it rotates
    //in X axis
    public float pitchOffset = 0;

    //Controls the yaw of the camera where it rotates
    //in Y axis
    public float yawOffset = 0;

    public float distanceFromObject = 6f;
    void Update()
    {
        //Creation of the look offset relative to the
        //Observable position
        Vector3 lookOffset = playerObject.position;
        lookOffset.y += pitchOffset;
        lookOffset.x += yawOffset;

        Vector3 lookOnObject = playerObject.position - transform.position;
        //Replaced playerObject.position with lookOffset
        lookOnObject = lookOffset - transform.position;
        transform.forward = lookOnObject.normalized;


        Vector3 playerLastPosition;
        //Replaced playerObject.position with lookOffset
        playerLastPosition = lookOffset - lookOnObject.normalized * distanceFromObject;

        playerLastPosition.y = playerObject.position.y + distanceFromObject / 2;
        transform.position = playerLastPosition;
    }
}
```

It could be done with Vector3 or Vector2 where you store the pitchOffset, and yawOffset to x and y fields.

Comment: Hi! I'm really new to C# so I would really appreciate it if you could add it in for me because the problem that I have had is that you can't assign an integer or float value to Vector3 (at least not how I've been doing it).     Vector3 lookOfset = 3;

Comment: The script was too long, so I edited my answer. Feel free to check it out.